# How to delete dlls after stopping windows service in DOS / win command prompt / windows batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, dos, command-prompt

```
::Stop Windows service
sc query MyWinService | find "STOPPED" & if errorlevel 1 net stop MyWinService
::delete the dll
del /q  E:\MyWinService\\*
for /d  %%x  in (E:\MyWinService\\*)  do  @rd  /s  /q  "%%x"
```

But some of the dlls not get deleted and the output comes as `----"ACCESS DENIED"----` if I re-run the same command after 5 minutes it executes. I know because the dll is still associated with the windows service so error is coming but I want to delete the dlls without re-running the command again after 5 min. :(

Comment: could you wait a little like 60 second after execution of net stop in batch file? like waiting like this: "PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL" it will wait 60 sec. is it possible for you? Then the next line could be del command

Comment: Is there any way to rerun the same command till "access denied" error is coming in loop?

Comment: batch file or powershell way?

Answer (score 3):

Batch file way

```
:Repeat
del "del /q E:\MyWinService\*"
if exist "E:\MyWinService\sampledll.dll" goto Repeat
```

Comment: Thanx a ton vahid. I am a new user so cant hit like to ur answer. but thanx dude. I didnt knw about goto statement. :D

Answer (score 1):

Powershell way:

```
do
{
  $a = stop-service MyWinService -PassThru
 }while ($a.status -ne "Stopped")
    do
 {
 remove-item e:\MyWinService\* -recurse -force -ea silentlycontinue
 } untill ( (dir e:\mywinservice).count -gt 0 )
```

Comment: My code is stopping the service successfully but doesnot allow to delete the dll for the next 5 min or so.

Comment: @user2003886 Was thinking the problem is the delay on stopping the service that locking the .dll.